# How do I make a 'cover' for my email address

Tags: email, github, domain-name

I want to make links for people to email me in github pages but I don't want them to know my actual email. I noticed that username@github.com may be a valid email address. But when I tried emailing that address, I got this:
[image]

How do I modify the organisational settings to allow users to email me in Github. If not possible, how do I set up an email for [my github page](https://azlancoding.github.io) such that it becomes *email@azlancoding.github.io*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub doesn't provide email address services for users.  The domain github.com is used for GitHub staff and company usage, and GitHub doesn't offer email for github.io domains, either.  Email is a service that requires extensive abuse management, both incoming and outgoing, and most sites don't want to provide that service as a result.

You can always set up an additional account, either on your own domain or elsewhere, that forwards to your real account.  How to do that is probably more on topic for SuperUser, assuming you're setting up the software yourself.